# How to keep an Android app running indefinitely?

Tags: android, service

I am writing an Android app which must always be running in the background until the user exits it from the app's menu. But now I notice that in Android after some time my app is stopped by itself without user intervention.

Any idea how to make sure my app will always be running in the background?

Comment: It stops it when memory is over and it needs it for another app

Comment: Please consider marking some of your questions with accepted answers so that others can benefit from them.

Answer (score 11):

You need to run a Service of your own.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Answer (score 7):

If you need to run at all times, look into a `Service` and [`startForeground`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29). If you can let your `Service` die but get restarted, look into [`onStartCommand`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29) and [`START_STICKY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY).

Comment: I am doing same. working fine in nexus 5. But in xiaomi service is getting killed as soon as my application is killing.

Comment: `startForeground` is not a panacea for this, the app still gets closed by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

For your application, in the manifest xml, put:

android:persistent="true"

Comment: From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#persistent):  
 Applications should not normally set this flag; persistence mode is intended only for certain system applications.

Comment: My answer is technically accurate and meets the poster's requirement for "must be always running in the background".

Comment: Setting things persistent [only works for apps included with the system image](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/2E10ZSnaK2Q/csXFYPchqcIJ).

Comment: very good. "certain system applications" is no longer vague with that information. Thanks for clearing it up - I learned something new today.

Answer (score 0):

AndroidMainfest.xml looks like this with presistent=true:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="7" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:persistent="true">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Only works for apps included with the system image . See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529834/how-to-keep-a-android-app-always-running#comment6799178_5811609

Answer (score 0):

> “While the app development documentation does explain the role of
>   android:persistent, the use of that attribute is reserved for apps that
>   are built within the AOSP.”
>
> – Embedded Android